# Calculation of disparity in parallel stereo cameras

Tags: computer-vision, stereo-vision

I'm learning about stereo vision and the slides that my teacher provided aren't very clear on this point. He had a formula for disparity:
$$d = \begin{cases}
    x_L ‒ x_R & \text{if } x_R \ge 0 \\
    | x_L | + |x_R| & \text{if } x_R < 0
    \end{cases}
$$

And I had a gut feeling that this wasn't right. I then looked up other information on the subject and found [these slides](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Efidler/slides/2015/CSC420/lecture12_hres.pdf) from a university in toronto. But in one slide the formula shows as:

$$d=x_R​−x_L​$$

And the slide next they show it as

$$d=x_L​−x_R​$$

Which is the right formula, or which formula do I choose, based on which variable?

Comment: so, what do the letters $d$, $x_L$ and $x_R$ actually mean in your context? the same letters can have different definitions in different material.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use left or right. Immensely should be understanding how to do it from an x y point of view, that makes the most sense intuitively. When you're finding the difference in between a left and right audio signal, it doesn't matter either which side goes first in the equation as long as you sum everything right at the end

Comment: @MarcusMüller $d$ is the disparity, $x_L$ and $x_R$ are the positions of the measured point in the left and the right camera respectively

Comment: @bandybabboon Fair enough, but I did get confused by the equation my teacher provided me with. I don't think $|x_L| + |x_R|$ can be right, right? I thought maybe $|x_L - x_R|$ would be the best if you expect $d$ to always be positive...? I just need to know for sure what the formula is...

Comment: @Typhaon yep, gathered that, but since you're asking about signs, you need to be very specific on *how* these positions are measured, where exactly their "0" is and where positive and negative numbers go. This is very, very very likely the difference between publications that come to different signs in formulas for the same thing.